# how does one add accessories to a sculpted mesh?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

i am a novice modeler who i looking for some a modeling advice.

here is an image of a creature that i would like to model, (IMAGE BY ALEX CHEN, found on creature spot dot com)

[image]

this is my sculpted progress so far,

[image]

i just can't figure out how to add the wings and the armor like material for the chest and arms. As you can see from my mesh i tried to use and array modifier, along with shrink wrap, and subdivision surface modifiers but so far i am not getting the results that i want.

Your (the viewer reading this question) answer can really help us novice modeler in the long run. What is the best approach to adding accessories to sculpted mesh?

Comment: I'd say one of often used approaches, at lest as for adding accesories, is by duplicating adjacent part of sculpted mesh and editing it so to make it look like desired. This is applicable to clothes/armores most, though. As for wings, it seems it would be easier to model from scratch

Comment: Consider using a Shrinkwrap modifier as well

Comment: if i model the wings by themselves they will be a static mesh, which is not what i want because i am going to make an animation out of this character. (it will spread its wings)

Comment: Add an armature for the wings as well (assuming it is being added for the character). No matter in what order you will model them, to animate the result you still need to have something to animate

Comment: notice the wings, how curved they are. Let assume the wing can represent a flag. how does one achieve that shape. I mean look real closely at the wings on the concept are, those folds, how, just how? sculpting would be too exhaustive. Modeling, maybe! but are there some modifiers that i can use to get the shape of the wing. Maybe a  beizer curve! i just don't know, i have spent the longest time just looking at the model, simply staring at it. Any help, much appreciated!

Comment: the wings could represent a plane, which has a subdivision surface modifier. Then i could dynamically sculpt the rest of the detail, such as the tears in the wings, but interns of the curvature. Would bezier curves be the solution. They might, but how!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This process will work for parts that are attached permanently to the creature only. You only see gear/armor swapping in game design, because it is streamlined to be that way. If you want to be able to switch out gear quickly, you're working with the wrong program.

But you **can** change the materials and look of the parts easily, as I will show you here.

Make sure you are in Cycles and have created a UV for your model. In your node creation create three materials, one for the creature, one for the armor, and one for the wings. Put all the node groups into one material, link them together via a mix shader governed by a black and white texture. Make sure the texture is high resolution to avoid ambiguity in the border between the materials.

You can later come back and tweak the materials without having done any destructive editing.

Note: if you will share the .blend I can give you more specific instructions.